# PHP > mkdir path issues

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm currently working on a website admin panel,
I added a form that adds clients to the database, what I want to do now, is to create folders for them via PHP.

So I tried to do that using the function: mkdir(),
The problem is, that when I tested the function on my "Xampp" server, it all worked just as i wanted it to.

But when I moved the file to the real host that I will use via FTP, and It just wont work the same..

ill try to explain whats wrong..:

```
mkdir('folderName'); //this will create a folder that i cant access through the FTP
mkdir('folderName', 0777); //creates a folder that i can access, but cant open other folders in it and cant change chmod permissions
```

I also need to create some nested folders for example:

```
mkdir('folderName/anotherFolder',0777,true); //this works on the host but again, the folders are not letting me change chmod permissions and cant create folders in them
```

in my xampp server i could create a few folders in a given path for example:

```
mkdir('folderName');
mkdir('folderName/one');
mkdir('folderName/two');
```

the above examples arent working on my host..

So yea sorry for writing so much, I just thought that you guys need to know those things..
Anyways, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `chgrp` as well as `chmod`.

Other than that, the best solution in such ostensible FS situations is to do it via FTP. Major frameworks do this (including Joomla and Wordpress).

Comment: Thanks mate! I didn't know about those FTP functions before :), ugh I'm such a noob..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not the owner of files/directories created by PHP script.